# Completely drop Unity for Gnome on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, gnome, 14.04, desktop-environments

I've been using Ubuntu for a long time, so I know the troubles of attempting to install the two alongside each other.. What I don't know is what the best way to completely drop Unity for Gnome is.

So far, my options appear to be the following:

1. Back up my home folder & whatever else I need then simply install Ubuntu GNOME
2. Install gnome-shell & ubuntu-gnome-desktop packages then clean up Unity
3. Switch out Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu GNOME repositories

The first option is what I'll likely do, since the second option apparently causes a plethora of problems. The third option, however, seems nice, and I haven't come across nearly enough clear information regarding switching repositories to either choose or disregard it.

What do you think about these three options? Which would you suggest? Would option three work?

**UPDATE:** Decided to go with backup / reinstall. There still isn't enough information about switching repositories for me to take the risk at the moment. I hope that one day users can switch repositories to swap between Ubuntu flavors..

Comment: I don't see the troubles to install both, unity and gnome-shell are just diferent shells for the gnome desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not wipe your install and put on http://ubuntugnome.org/ ?

Comment: That was the first option I listed, and the one I said I'll likely use. Is there any other way to switch that will be clean and *hopefully* problem free?

Comment: I agree with this answer. I think backing up data is less trouble than messing around with repositories.

Comment: I think you're right. It will also give me an excuse to clean up the home folder.. let's see if anyone else has an idea

Comment: @merb I think you are best off with this "nuclear option", it's how I roll. Thumb drives and cheap, so are external hdd's. I installed Ubuntu-GNOME when the devs froze it before release, and have been mostly very happy with it. I have to relearn how to customize things in Gnome3, but isn't that half the fun of FOSS? ;) Good luck.